# How to parse .ini file and generate code in php

Tags: php, ini

I'm new to .ini and php. I'm using PFBC to generate form fields. This is the code sample to generate one form field:

```
$form->addElement(new Element\T_COMPANY("", "company", array(
"required" => 1,
"placeholder" => "*Bedrijf:",
)));
```

I need to read an .ini file and based on what is in that .ini to generate one or more lines of code to make the form field.
The .ini file will contain some thing like :

```
fields[company] = T_COMPANY,"","company",1,"*Company"
```

where `T_COMPANY` is the identifier to generate this block of code `$form->addElement(new Element\T_COMPANY(` next `""` is the identifier  for `""` in the php code next `"company"` is the identifier  for `"company"` in the php code next  `1` identifier  for `"required" => 1,` in the php and the last one `"*Bedrijf"` identifier  for `"placeholder" => "*Bedrijf:",`
Any idea on how to do this ?

I tried to use foreach to construct the syntax but is not working

```
foreach ($formConfig as $elementConfig) {
    switch (strtolower($elementConfig['type'])) {
    case 'text':
        $className = 'Element\T_COMPANY';
            break;
    default:
      throw new Exception();
      break;
  }
  $formElement = new $className("", "Required", array( 
    "required" => 1,
    "placeholder" => "*Bedrijf:",
    ));
  $form->addElement($formElement);
}
$form = new Form($formConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me

```
foreach ($ini_array['FORM_SETTINGS'] as $type => $fieldsData) {

        if ($fieldsData['type'] == 'HTML'){
                $className = "PFBC\\Element\\{$fieldsData['type']}";
                $form->addElement(new $className($fieldsData['string']
                ));
            continue;}

        if ($fieldsData['required'] == true){
            $className = "PFBC\\Element\\{$fieldsData['type']}";
            $form->addElement(new $className($fieldsData['label'], $fieldsData['id'], array(
            'required' => $fieldsData['required'],
            'placeholder' => $fieldsData['placeholder'],
                )
            ));
        }

        if ($fieldsData['required'] == false){
            $className = "PFBC\\Element\\{$fieldsData['type']}";
            $form->addElement(new $className($fieldsData['label'], $fieldsData['id'], array(
            'placeholder' => $fieldsData['placeholder'],
                )
            ));
        }


}
```